# QGIS Smart Map Plugin - Error Running Interpolation

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, interpolation, kriging

I am new to using the Smart-Map plugin. I added my data and did the `ordinary Kriging interpolation`. Just before it reaches 100% I get the following error message:

```
An error has occurred while executing Python code: 

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ccw' 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users/ACER/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\Smart_Map\Smart_Map.py", line 3809, in pushButton_Krigagem_clicked
    Output_Layer_File_tiff = self.export_raster_to_qgis(Input_Table, Output_Layer_File_tiff, Output_Layer_Name, z_field)
  File "C:\Users/ACER/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\Smart_Map\Smart_Map.py", line 8427, in export_raster_to_qgis
    self.define_raster_color_ramp(rlayer, Output_Layer_Name)
  File "C:\Users/ACER/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\Smart_Map\Smart_Map.py", line 8526, in define_raster_color_ramp
    QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(classes[2], QColor(int(stops[6]),int(stops[7]),int(stops[8]),int(stops[9])), '%.6f' % classes[2]),
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'ccw'


Python version: 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.28.1-Firenze Firenze, fde3b8fbb8c 
Python Path:
C:\Users/ACER/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\generate_swmm_inp
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.1/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/ACER/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/ACER/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.1\bin\python39.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.28.1\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/ACER/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\mmqgis/forms
C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\site-packages
D:/Belajar Smart Map
```

Can anyone tell me, what's the problem and how to resolves?

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is a hardcoded QGIS version in Smart_Map.py, I changed it to 3.30:

[image]

I also got an error related to extracting the layer Coordinate reference system in the same file, I hardcoded mine ('2154'), seems to work, though obviously not ideal

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

See link: https://github.com/gustavowillam/SmartMapPlugin/issues/49
The newest version of Smart-Map has fixed the problem.